# Turning Java into an Android app. Added elif and project crashes on load

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm currently working on turning some old Java code into a functioning android app. I used JavaFX to make the program originally but that won't work for android.

What i'm trying to do is, on a button click, the app should store what the user has selected and just hold it. For some reason this causes the code to crash and i'm not sure what the issue is. After that all I need to do is get it to output the selected items and make sure that the app is randomizing the array output for the workouts.

[This is the Android code on Github.](https://github.com/PevlorM/Android-workout/blob/main/Final/app/src/main/java/com/example/afinal/MainActivity.java)

[This is the original JavaFX code.](https://github.com/PevlorM/Android-workout/blob/main/Final/app/src/main/java/com/example/afinal/MainActivity.java)

```
package com.example.afinal;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     private ArrayList<MuscleItem> mMuscleList;
     private MuscleAdapter mAdapter;
     private ArrayList<RepItem> mRepList;
     private RepAdapter mRepAdapter;
     private final List<String> backList = new ArrayList<>();
     private final List<String> chestList = new ArrayList<>();
     private final List<String> legList = new ArrayList<>();

     Button btnWorkout;

    private String selectMuscles(String[] arr) {
          return (Arrays.toString(arr));
   }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnWorkout = findViewById(R.id.btnWorkout);
    btnWorkout.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Intent intent_one = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent_one);

    });

    initList();
    Spinner spinnerMuscles = findViewById(R.id.spinner_muscles);
    mAdapter = new MuscleAdapter(this, mMuscleList);
    spinnerMuscles.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    spinnerMuscles.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            MuscleItem clickedItem = (MuscleItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String clickedMuscleName = clickedItem.getmuscleName();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, clickedMuscleName + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            //This causes the program to crash.
            /*
            String cMuscle = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String muscleChoice = "";
            //selection trees to figure out which muscle group and which type
            //of workout
            if (cMuscle.equalsIgnoreCase("Chest Day")) {
                muscleChoice = selectMuscles(chestDay());
            } else if (cMuscle.equalsIgnoreCase("Leg Day")) {
                muscleChoice = selectMuscles(legDay());
            } else if (cMuscle.equalsIgnoreCase("Back Day")) {
                muscleChoice = selectMuscles(backDay());
            }
             */
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    initList();
    Spinner spinnerRep = findViewById(R.id.spinner_repetition);
    mRepAdapter = new RepAdapter(this, mRepList);
    spinnerRep.setAdapter(mRepAdapter);
    spinnerRep.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            RepItem clickedItemRep = (RepItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String clickedMuscleName = clickedItemRep.getrepName();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, clickedMuscleName + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //THis causes it to crash as well
            /*
            String cRep = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String repChoice = "";
            if (cRep.equalsIgnoreCase("Lose Weight")) {
                repChoice = "5 sets of 20 reps, with 1 minute of cardio between";
            } else if (cRep.equalsIgnoreCase("Gain muscle mass")) {
                repChoice = "4 sets of 10 reps, or 5 sets of 8 reps";
            } else if (cRep.equalsIgnoreCase("Gain strength")) {
                repChoice = "5 sets of 3 reps, increasing the weight\n"
                        + "until you can no longer lift the weight.";
            }
             */
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}

private void initList() {
    mMuscleList = new ArrayList<>();
    mMuscleList.add(new MuscleItem("Back", R.drawable.back));
    mMuscleList.add(new MuscleItem("Chest", R.drawable.chest));
    mMuscleList.add(new MuscleItem("Legs", R.drawable.legs));


    mRepList = new ArrayList<>();
    mRepList.add(new RepItem("Gain muscle mass", R.drawable.mass));
    mRepList.add(new RepItem("Gain strength", R.drawable.strength));
    mRepList.add(new RepItem("Lose weight", R.drawable.weight));


}
    private String[] backDay() {
        if (backList.isEmpty()) {
            backList.add("Deadlift");
            backList.add("Pull Up");
            backList.add("Back Rows");
            backList.add("Bend-Over Barbell Rows");
            backList.add("Romanian Deadlift");
            backList.add("Front Squat");
            backList.add("Incline Dumbbell Row");
            backList.add("Chinup");
            backList.add("Trap-Bar Deadlift");
            backList.add("Alternating Dumbbell Row");
            backList.add("Inverted Row");
            backList.add("Swiss Ball Leg Curl");
            backList.add("Wide-Grip Pullup");
            backList.add("Landmine One-Arm Row");
            backList.add("Burpee");
            backList.add("Lying Lateral Raise");
            backList.add("Hang Clean");
        }
        return randomExercises(backList);
    }

    private String[] chestDay() {
        if (chestList.isEmpty()) {
            chestList.add("Bench Press");
            chestList.add("Incline Press");
            chestList.add("Dip");
            chestList.add("Flye");
            chestList.add("Reverse Flye");
            chestList.add("Supine Press");
            chestList.add("Chest Press Machine");
            chestList.add("Low-Incline Press");
            chestList.add("Speed Bench Press");
            chestList.add("Landmine Press");
            chestList.add("Floor Press");
            chestList.add("Prone Flye");
            chestList.add("Pullover");
            chestList.add("Plate Pressout");
            chestList.add("3-Way Flye");
            chestList.add("Pushup");
        }
        return randomExercises(chestList);
    }

    private String[] legDay() {
        if (legList.isEmpty()) {
            legList.add("Squat");
            legList.add("Leg Press");
            legList.add("Leg Extension");
            legList.add("Dumbbell Step Up");
            legList.add("Body Weight Calf Raises");
            legList.add("Walking Lunge");
            legList.add("Front Squat");
            legList.add("Bulgarian Split Squat");
            legList.add("Dumbbell Stepup");
            legList.add("Swiss Ball Leg Curl");
            legList.add("Single-Leg Romanian Deadlift");
            legList.add("Pause Squat");
            legList.add("Reverse Lunge");
            legList.add("Dumbbell Squat");
            legList.add("Kettlebell Swing");
            legList.add("Jump Squat");
            legList.add("Barbell Calf Raise");
        }
        return randomExercises(legList);
    }


    private String[] randomExercises(List<String> arr) {
        Collections.shuffle(arr);
        return arr.subList(0, 4).toArray(new String[3]);
    }
}
```

Here is the FATAL ERROR in the log

2020-12-12 22:21:56.300 8022-8022/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.afinal, PID: 8022
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.afinal.MuscleItem cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at com.example.afinal.MainActivity$1.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:55)
at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:957)
at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:946)
at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:55)
at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:910)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Comment: Show us the stacktrace.  That will probably explain why it crashes.

Comment: @StephenC I'm new to Android. I'm not familiar with stacktrace, so i'm not sure how to do that. But I am working on it right now. I think I found the error code in the log. I will add it to my post

Comment: Are you also new to Java? It is a simple ClassCastException as the stacktrace clearly states. And what's with the elif in your question's title?

Comment: @Ridcully Yes I am, I took a class on it and i'm trying to brush up on my skills after not using it. The program works fine until I put the code in, which included the elif so I blamed the elif and not the casting for some reason, I have some bad brain fog after contracting covid about a month ago.

Comment: @Mpev - Use logcat to look for stacktraces; see https://developer.android.com/games/optimize/crash

Comment: Also, as Ridcully points out, Java doesn't have an `elif` keyword.  While we can **guess** what you mean in this context, you shouldn't force us to guess ... if you want accurate answers.

Comment: Correct, I'm using an if else if loop. I just short handed it to elif. That was my mistake I do try to be as thorough as I can when I ask for help and always provide the code I am having an issue with. The answer below worked for me and now I can keep chugging along slowly. Thank you for your time!

Comment: There is no if-loop. Loop is a conditional, so it would be an if-else-if-statement. Using the right words will help you be understood.

Comment: Just a side note: Your statement that your JavaFX code is not suited for Android is not really true. With Gluons client-maven-plugin you can compile JavaFX apps into an APK and run it on any Android device. The same is true for iOS. https://github.com/gluonhq/client-maven-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each item in your adapter is a `MuscleItem`, not a `String`. So when you try to cast the result of `getItemAtPosition()`, an exception is thrown.

> ```
> //This causes the program to crash.
> /*
> String cMuscle = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
> ```

It looks like the `MuscleItem` class has a `getmuscleName()` method; probably you want to use that instead:

```
MuscleItem clickedItem = (MuscleItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
String cMuscle = clickedItem.getmuscleName();
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! Between not touching Java for a year and covid brain fog this has been very rough figuring this all out.